# How do I print an ArrayList reading top-to-bottom in Java?

Tags: java, list, arraylist, mean

So I was able to add values to my ArrayList as per requirement of my program, but now I need to print these values to be read vertically, like each value in the list but not printed in a long line. With my code below...

```
public class Homework23Average {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList exes = new ArrayList ();
        double x;
        double y = 0;
        Scanner inputStream = null;

        try {
            inputStream = new Scanner (new File ("RawData.txt"));
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println ("File not found, program aborted:");
            System.exit (1);
        }
        int count = 0;
        while (inputStream.hasNextDouble ()) {
            count ++;
            x = inputStream.nextDouble ();
            y += x;
            if (x > y/count) // x values greater than the mean (y/count)
                exes.add (x);
        }
        System.out.println ("This value(s) greater than the mean (" + y/count + ") are (is):" + exes);
        System.out.println ("This is the sum of all x values: " + y);
        System.out.println ("This is the mean of the x values: " + y/count);
```

... I get the results from the ArrayList printed out horizontally:
i.e.

```
[120.3, 215.9, 165.0, 185.0, 185.4, 160.5, 120.4, 370.1, ....... 125.3]
```

I need the results to be printed vertically:
i.e.

```
120.3
215.9
165.0
185.0
.
.
.
125.3
```

Is this even possible with ArrayLists?
Should I be using some other method to get this done?

Note that this is my second program writing in Java after "Hello World".

Comment: Yes, just write a for loop to print all the values in the list on a single line for each one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not natively supported, but you can use a simple loop:

```
for (Object o : exes)
    System.out.println(o);
```

or use regex kung fu for a one-liner:

```
System.out.println(exes.toString().replaceAll("^.|.$", "").replace(", ", "\n"));
```

which modifies the output of the `toString()` to the format you want.

or in java 8:

```
exes.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Your first option will be better because of the fact toString() in ArrayList will any way iterate through the list. You can avoid overhead of regex.

Comment: or Java8 kung fu `exes.forEach(o -> System.out.println(o));`

Comment: @zapl: `exes.forEach(System.out::println);`

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom arr, thank you, I though that doesn't work in this case. Really need to read up on the whole lambda syntax :)

Comment: @Bohemian: see [Iterable.forEach](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html#forEach-java.util.function.Consumer-) -- creating a stream not required.

Answer (score 0):

If it is local I just do a lot of small ArrayList or Arrays. It is not recommended because it takes a bit of Memory but when it is a local app to pull in information I make something easier to read. If only it was local to the IDE I would use that version or a a Collections option in my IDE. I suggest following the advice of the more seasoned vets. They would know best practices.
Also the "for loop" would be fine just have to do gets for your information and normal setup for the "for loop".

```
ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
        ArrayList list2 = new ArrayList();
        ArrayList list3 = new ArrayList();
        ArrayList list4 = new ArrayList();
        ArrayList list5 = new ArrayList();
        ArrayList list6 = new ArrayList();
        ArrayList list7 = new ArrayList();
        ArrayList list8 = new ArrayList();

        list.add("Fuel Cost" + " " + costOctane + "  ");
        list2.add("Car Fuel Cost" + " " + totalFuelCost + "  ");
        list3.add("Life Left In Tire (Rough Est.)" + "  " + tireWear + "  ");
        list4.add("Miles Driven" + " " + miles + "  ");
        list5.add("Trips In City Base on Miles Driven: " + "  " + TripCity + "  ");
        list6.add("City Fuel Capacity Based on Average City Driving: " + " " + CityFuleEcon + "  ");
        list7.add("Trips on Hwy Base on Miles Driven: " + " " + TripHwy + "  ");
        list8.add("City Fuel Capacity Based on Average Highway Driving: " + " " + HwyFuleEcon + "  ");

        System.out.println(" This is Your Est. Operation Cost " + list + "\n"
                + list2 + "\n"
                + list3 + "\n"
                + list4 + "\n"
                + list5 + "\n"
                + list6 + "\n"
                + list7 + "\n"
                + list8);
```

The outcome looks great and if you are printing to file it comes out vertically.

Program:

```
Fuel Cost
3.21
Tank Capacity
15
Month(s) On Tire
42
Mileage Driven Today
90
This is the total For Gas:  

48.15
**************************************
**************************************
 This is Your Est. Operation Cost [Fuel Cost 3.21  ]
[Car Fuel Cost 48.15  ]
[Life Left In Tire (Rough Est.)  7.800000000000004  ]
[Miles Driven 90  ]
[Trips In City Base on Miles Driven:   3.1666666666666665  ]
[City Fuel Capacity Based on Average City Driving:  285.0 miles  ]
[Trips on Hwy Base on Miles Driven:  4.0  ]
[City Fuel Capacity Based on Average Highway Driving:  360.0 miles ]

Entry Completed On: 2018.Jun.30 at 12:29:42 EDT
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 15 seconds)
```

File look just like the ArrayList setup...... Pretty

```
***************************
Before

Your Cost Of Operations
[Fule Cost 3.21  , Car Fule Cost 48.15  , Life Left In Tire (Rough Est.)  7.800000000000004  , Miles Driven 90  , Trips In City Base on Miles Driven:   3.1666666666666665  , City Fuel Capacity Based on Average City Driving:  285.0  , Trips on Hwy Base on Miles Driven:  4.0  , City Fuel Capacity Based on Average Highway Driving:  360.0  ]
Entry Completed On: 2018.Jun.29 at 11:59:05 EDT
***************************
***************************

AFTER

Your Cost Of Operations
[Fule Cost 3.21  ]
[Car Fule Cost 48.15  ]
[Life Left In Tire (Rough Est.)  7.800000000000004  ]
[Miles Driven 90  ]
[Trips In City Base on Miles Driven:   3.1666666666666665  ]
[City Fuel Capacity Based on Average City Driving:  285.0  ]
[Trips on Hwy Base on Miles Driven:  4.0  ]
[City Fuel Capacity Based on Average Highway Driving:  360.0  ]
Entry Completed On: 2018.Jun.30 at 12:20:54 EDT
***************************
***************************
Your Cost Of Operations
[Fule Cost 3.21  ]
[Car Fule Cost 48.15  ]
[Life Left In Tire (Rough Est.)  7.800000000000004 Months  ]
[Miles Driven 90  ]
[Trips In City Base on Miles Driven:   3.1666666666666665  ]
[City Fuel Capacity Based on Average City Driving:  285.0  ]
[Trips on Hwy Base on Miles Driven:  4.0  ]
[City Fuel Capacity Based on Average Highway Driving:  360.0  ]
Entry Completed On: 2018.Jun.30 at 12:29:42 EDT
***************************
```

Still got the brackets yet to me it much easier to read.